# How to invoke transfinite recursion

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

Transfinite recursion states that

> For any $F:\mathbf{V}\to \mathbf{V}$, there exists a unique $G:\mathbf{ON}\to\mathbf{V}$ such that $\forall\alpha[G(\alpha)=F(G\vert_\alpha)]$

where $\mathbf{V}$ denotes the universe of all sets and $\mathbf{ON}$ denotes the class of all ordinals. I want to use this theorem to define ordinal addition. Inuitively, I want to define it as such: Fix $\alpha\in\mathbf{ON}$. Then

- $\alpha+0=\alpha$,
- $\alpha+S(\beta)=S(\alpha+\beta)$,
- $\alpha+\beta=\sup\{\alpha+\xi:\xi<\beta\}$ if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

When invoking the theorem to prove that this definition makes sense, we want $G(\beta)=\alpha+\beta$. How do I define $F$ in order to invoke the theorem?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I don't think that works because ordinals are not functions. But the theorem is taking $G(\beta)=F(G\vert_\beta)$ which is applying $F$ to a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: So the input of $F$ is a function $f$ on the ordinals... define $F(f)$ by cases on whether the domain of $f$ is zero, successor, or limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few hints:

- $F$ should be defined piecewise (i.e., by cases).
- It only matters how we define $F$ on sets that could be equal to $G|_\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \textbf{ON}$. For all other "non-interesting" input sets, we can let $F$ be equal to anything.
- On the "interesting" input sets, we should define $F$ by cases depending on whether the input could be equal to $G|_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$ equal to zero, a successor, or a limit.

So, if we are using the standard definition of a "$x$ is a function" as "$x$ is a set of ordered pairs, with each first coordinate corresponding to a unique second coordinate," our definition of $F$ might look something like this:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} ???? & x \text{ is not a function} \vee (x \text{ is a function} \wedge \text{dom}(x) \notin \textbf{ON}) \newline
???? & x \text{ is a function} \wedge \text{dom}(x) = 0 \newline
???? & x \text{ is a function} \wedge \text{dom}(x) = S(\beta) \text{ for some } \beta \in \textbf{ON} \newline
???? & x \text{ is a function} \wedge \text{dom}(x) = \beta \text{ for some limit } \beta \in \textbf{ON} \newline
 \end{cases},$$
where $\text{dom}(x)$ denotes the domain of $x$ and where you should fill in the ????'s with correct expressions depending on $x$.

To ensure that this method is rigorous, make note of the following facts:

- The $F$ that we define and the $G$ that the transfinite recursion theorem guarantees are not *set functions*, (i.e., neither of them is equal to a set in $V$). However, they are well-defined *class functions*, (i.e., each of them is captured by a formula in the language of set theory).
- In order to make sure that $F$ as written above is captured a formula in the language of set theory, make sure that the expressions "$x$ is a function," "$\text{dom}(x) = y$," "$x \in \textbf{ON}$," and "$x \text{ is a limit}$" are each captured by a formula in the language of set theory.

I hope these hints help!